# What or who is a "Scholli"?

Tags: translation, phrase, colloquial, idiom

I hear people say:

> "Mein lieber Scholli, das war knapp!"

What does *"Scholli"* mean in this context? Is using this idiom in any way offensive or insulting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Scholli)

> mein lieber Scholli!

is a colloquial expression of astonishment, admiration or relief.

It's derived from the French word **"joli"** which means *"pretty/cute"* or *"nice"*.

Comment: +1; didn't know the French origin (though it sounds logical), though I often hear the expression.

Answer (score 9):

Nice Question, you never think about those if you are just familiar with them.
de.wikipedia.org has another explanation:
https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/wiki/Mein_lieber_Scholli

"Die andere Theorie besagt, dass Scholli auf eine reale Person zurückgeht, nämlich auf Ferdinand Joly"
According to Wikipedia he was a vagrant in Austria who lived a very own kind of lifestyle.

And to your Question, no it would be in no way offensive to use this. Maybe some people would find it funny to hear a foreigner say this (even for German people this is not a common expression, at least not for my age).