# Meaning of "mein Lieber"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does phrase *"mein Lieber"* mean *"my beloved one"* (i.e. can/should be used when addressing someone very close) or more like *"my dear"* (i.e. phrase you could use for both someone close to you and someone that isn't close to you but when you want to be polite) or does it depend on the context?

Comment: *my dear* ist mehr *mein Geliebter*

Comment: Actually, “mein Lieber” is very rarely used to address someone, with the possible exception of the use mentioned in Thorsten's answer.  So maybe you want to check where you encountered the word and expand your question. The phrases “lieber xxx” and “mein lieber xxx” are different from this.

Comment: @Vogel612, I do not agree. “Geliebter” is mostly used with sexual connotations.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz can you then provide a more fitting translation??

Comment: Ich habe das Wort "exact" aus der Frage entfernt. Es macht wenig Sinn in Fragen der Sprache nach exacter Bedeutung zu fragen. Entweder ein Begriff passt oder er passt nicht. Man kann sagen 3 Tage nach Sonntag ist ungefähr Donnerstag, aber Mittwoch ist exact - aber man sieht schon, dass das keinen Sinn macht. Wenn ich sage "Der Platz war leer" obwohl dort 3 Leute standen, dann ist es falsch. Fast leer wäre richtig, aber exact? Exact wäre "Es waren 3 Leute da".

Comment: @Vogel612 No (except *mein Lieber*, which is better, though not very good for the reasons given ;) ), but fortunately the question does not require find a translation for *my dear*. Anyway, as far as I know, *my dear* is something that a parent might say to their child, and in that context I would not think that a German parent would say *mein Geliebter*.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz right you are. Different Attempt: *mein Schatz*, obwohl ich das ja am ehesten mit *my precious* zurückübersetzen würde ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the usage of *"mein lieber"* does occur in proverbs such as *"mein lieber... [Scholli](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/what-or-who-is-a-scholli), Schwan, etc."*, and in colloquial speech for astonishment or even [reprimand](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8016/23) this is by no means restricted to these in contemporary German.

Using *"mein lieber..."* to address people still is used to emphasize a loving relationship but it has become less common especially amongst younger people. It is more often seen in written language:

#### Letter

> Meine liebe Erika,

When starting a letter by adding *"Mein"* to the *liebe* it will emphasize the loving feelings we have to a husband, wife, son, daughter, parents or the like. It is somewhat old-fashioned but there is no reason to not use it, even when you are in your early twens. Your parents will love you for writing a letter with *"Meine lieben Eltern,..."*.

#### Written text

Whenever we use *"mein lieber"* together with a name it can be an expression for both, a true emphasis of the love we feel, or for an ironical tone. This will depend entirely on the context.

When used in plural *"Meine Lieben"* will be used in the meaning of our own family.

#### Obituay

Still today the most common term found in an obituary note is indeed *"mein lieber"*, or *"meine liebe"* as in

> Mein lieber Ehemann und unser guter Vater hat uns heute für immer verlassen.

Comment: Valid points, but they relate only to the usage of "liebe/r" as an adjective, right? As I understood the question, REACHUS is primarily interested in "Lieber" used as a noun.

Comment: People may come here by Google and need to find the usage of *mein lieber* irrespect of noun or adjective. I deliberately left out the meaning and usage of *Lieber* as a noun to give room for edits on the existing answers ;)

Comment: Ah, ok -- good point! :)

Comment: Das finde ich keine gute Idee. Man sollte die gestellte Frage beantworten, nicht über's Eck was sich jemand fragen könnte, der via Google gekommen ist.

Comment: @userunknown: schön, dass Du das keine gute Idee findest, aber es wurde gefragt *""my beloved one" (i.e. can/should be used when addressing someone very close)"* das kann nicht unbeantwortet bleiben oder gar abgestritten werden. Was die Nomenableitung genau bedeutet, sollte aber durchaus noch beantwortet werden, da bin ich ganz Deiner Meinung (*wink mit Zaunpfahl*).

Answer (score 6):

*Mein Lieber/mein lieber Freund/Freundchen* can also be used in the context where you reprimand somebody, as in

> Dass das nicht nochmal vorkommt, mein Lieber!
>   Pass mal auf, mein Freund!
>   Lass Dich nicht nochmal dabei erwischen, Freundchen!

Comment: Mein lieber Herr Gesangsverein.

Comment: Mein Lieber Scholli (oder so...)

Comment: Ironische Verwendungen gibt es so oft - die Antwort sollte m.E. immer erst die eigentliche Frage beantworten - was die ironische Verwendung betrifft ergibt sich dann oft daraus.

Comment: Die Frage war: Heißt "Mein Lieber" immer "my beloved" oder "my dear" oder kommt es auf den Zusammenhang an. Meine Antwort: Es kommt auf den Zusammenhang an. Daher: Ich habe die eigentliche Frage beantwortet, oder nicht?

Answer (score 4):

Ohne weitere Zusätze steht *mein Lieber* für einen eng Vertrauten, oft den männlichen Partner, analog *meine Liebe* für die Partnerin. Jedoch greift man eher zum Superlativ *meine Liebste*/*mein Liebster*.

Als Mann bevorzuge ich im Folgenden, von der Liebsten zu reden.

Da es eine vertrauliche Anrede ist, ist sie stark vom persönlichen Milieu geprägt und kann im persönlichen Gebrauch bis ins Absurde variiert werden. Von Tigerchen zu Schnuffel, Prinzessin bis Gebieterin, von Moppel bis Gazelle. Man hält sich hier nicht so an gesellschaftliche Konventionen, sondern schafft eigene.

Viele Menschen werden auch in der Öffentlichkeit nicht oder nicht all das verwenden, was sie im Schlafzimmer oder im Brief zum Ausdruck bringen.

Auf *Liebste* zu verzichten und zu *meine Liebe* zu greifen, kann in der Kommunikation also bedeuten, dass die Beziehung gerade etwas abgekühlt ist, oder dass man eine sehr unromantische Sache besprechen will, vielleicht auch, dass man Außenstehende nicht an Vertraulichkeiten teilhaben lassen will.

Abhängig von beruflicher Sphäre und Unternehmenskultur kann man aber auch den Kollegen oder Geschäftspartner, wenn eine herzliche Beziehung besteht, mit *mein Lieber* anschreiben (eher als anreden). Generell ist die Formulierung eher was für den Brief, und zwar als einleitende Anrede, denn für den mündlichen Gebrauch.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I'd have said that the meaning Thorsten is referring to is the prevailing one at present. 
In the meaning you refer to, it would sound old-fashioned and very quaint to me. I somehow associate it with the first half of the 20th century.

It actually really would be best, if you could clarify a bit more, especially in which direction your question is going, i.e. whether you've heard/read this, or if you want so say "my beloved one" and are looking for the right German phrase.

---

Not really helpful, but perhaps interesting -- here's what Google ngram says:

[mein Lieber](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mein%20Lieber&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) ("Lieber" as a noun inside a sentence): usage increase until ~1950, then decline

[Mein Lieber](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Mein%20Lieber&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) ("Lieber" as a noun at the beginning of a sentence - suggesting usage in greetings): the same, but overall much rarer.

[Mein Lieber, mein Lieber, mein lieber, Mein lieber](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Mein%20Lieber,mein%20Lieber,mein%20lieber,Mein%20lieber&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=): overview, including usage of "lieber" as an adjective.

Comment: Für die Suche am Beginn des Satzes hat NGram übrigens extra den Tag _START_, also füllt man ins Suchfeld `_START_ Mein Lieber`. Allerdings weiß ich nicht was einen sonst verleiten könnte das M groß zu schreiben. In den Links unten, als `About NGram viewer` findet sich weitere Information: [about ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info) .